# I will be asleep and I will asleep

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> I **will be** asleep by the time you get home, so please don’t make too much noise.
>
> I **will** asleep by the time you get home, so please don’t make too
>   much noise.*

What is the different between **will** and **will be**?

Comment: The second sentence doesn't work. you need to say either "I will be asleep", or perhaps "I will be sleeping".

Comment: 'will be" is the future tense of the auxilary verb "be".

Answer (score 4):

"I will be asleep" vs "I will asleep"

The first sentence is grammatically correct, but the second is not.

"Asleep" is an adjective, which means sleeping/not awake.  It needs an auxiliary verb before it in this sentence. The auxiliary verb "be" is there in the sentence, so it's correct.

"Asleep" is not a verb, so it's wrong to use it as a verb in the second sentence.

Answer (score 4):

*asleep* is an adjective, therefore you have to use the corresponding conjugated *to be* infront of it.

The same applies for these sentences:

> I am afraid.
>
> I was hungry. *(note that "was" also is "to be" just in a past tense)*
>
> I have been thirsty. *("have" is not "to be" therefore "been" had to be inserted)*